# Creating unevenly distributed events with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to generate time based events that are unevenly distributed using Pandas? I'm currently using this, but am trying to have variation in how evenly these events are distributed across the series.

```
rng = date_range('1/1/2011', periods=60*3, freq='S')
ts = Series(0, index=rng)
```

Comment: Unevenly how?  There are many different ways for a distribution to be uneven.

Comment: In that snippet, each event (0) occurs for every second during the range specified. I would like to somehow create a series where there's some variation in when these events happen. I'm trying to create sample test data to simulate events in a log file.

Comment: You can create timestamps any way you want.  But what I'm saying is you have to somehow define how you want them to be distributed.  You could, for instance, generate the every-second series and then grab a random subset of those.

Comment: Grabbing a random subset is a good idea, that would be a good solution and give me what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some example code based on the discussion in the comments.  You can set '0.50' to be any percentage to keep.

```
import numpy as np
ts = Series( np.random.uniform(0,1,180), index=rng)
ts[ ts < 0.50 ].dropna()

2011-01-01 00:00:00    0.283262
2011-01-01 00:00:01    0.200472
2011-01-01 00:00:04    0.077024
2011-01-01 00:00:06    0.041452
```